# ServiceStack new API for v3

Tags: servicestack

Is it possible to write

```
var request = new OrderRequest { Id = 1 };
var response = client.Get(request);
```

with ServiceStack v3.9.71?

According to https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/New-API it is, but I can't find the `IReturn<TResponse>` interface in this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're looking at the New API in the v3 wiki documentation.

The Get [API you're looking for exists in the v3 branch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/ServiceClientBase.cs#L918) as part of the `ServiceClientBase` API:

```
TResponse Get<TResponse>(IReturn<TResponse> request)
```

The `IReturn` interface markers you're looking for is in the [IService.cs class](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/8db80e293e9b3dd3ef2d225dbcdfc141ada80f63/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/IService.cs#L11) which is in the `ServiceStack.ServiceHost` namespace.

Using a productivity tool like [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/?gclid=CM66o9m4hsICFexr7AodrhwACw) will make it easier to find and add missing references, otherwise you can search [ServiceStack's GitHub v3 branch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/v3) online.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Then the question is whether I can use this New API functional in my projects for free as stable v3 assemblies? NuGet downloads v4 assemblies when I try to get 3.9.9.

Comment: @SergeP. Yes you can use v3 for free. You need to ensure you're only downloading v3 NuGet packages, see the [v3 download instructions](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3#referencing-v3-packages-in-new-projects) for examples on how to do this.

Comment: I've started with it. Exactly with PM> Install-Package ServiceStack -Version 3.9.71. As a result I get SS without IReturn. When I try to get 3.9.8 in the same way, Nuget downloads v4 assemblies.

Comment: @SergeP. Keep reading, [if you're using NuGet 2.8+](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3#how-to-install-if-using-nuget-28-or-higher) you need to specify `-DependencyVersion Highest` alternatively you can install the NuGet packages independently by ignoring the dependencies, all this info is on the linked docs.

Comment: Finally I did it by adding each dependency manually through NuGet console as described in https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Common/3.9.71 etc..
@mythz, thank you for your comprehensive help